# How do I change `stty intr` to another key combination in order to use ^c for zsh vi-mode?

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I wanted to use `Ctrl-c` to return to normal vim mode when using `zsh` in `vi-mode`. I managed to unmap it using:

```
stty intr ^-
stty intr undef
```

and then used `bindkey '^c' vi-cmd-mode` in my `.zshrc`. Everything is working fine but how do I reclaim my `Ctrl-c` functionality to a different key binding?

Comment: Leaving the question aside if it's wise to change the meaning of ^C: simply `stty intr ^E` or something similar isn't working?

Comment: @user2719058 Damn it I though I tried that! What I was doing is try to assign it to ctrl and **upper case** c and was ending up rebinding it to c as this does not seem possible.. :S . Submit it as answer so that I can accept it. And thanks :)

Comment: @user2719058 as to whether it is wise or not.. it is the only thing that can save me from continuously hitting it. I use it in Vim and the reflex is too strong...

Comment: By the way, regarding the tagging of this question, I think it is not so much shell-related, but terminal-related.

Comment: @Dionysis In vim `<C-c>` (unless mapped to escape) does not trigger abbreviations and InsertLeave event which (especially the second) is essential for some plugins. You can also accidentally cancel CursorHoldI and CursorMovedI autocommands if they are used by plugins (unlikely, but possible: these autocommands tend to be optimized since leaving them slow will disappoint the user much enough to delete the plugin right away). Latter will be the problem no matter whether or not `<C-c>` is mapped.

Comment: @ZyX Thanks for the advice!! I mapped it to escape with `inoremap <C-c> <ESC>` and for visual mode `vnoremap <C-c> <ESC>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding as an answer, for the record:

`stty intr ^E` or similar should work. :)

Comment: In shells where `^` has a special meaning (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125406/special-meaning-of-caret-in-solaris-bourne-sh) you can put the second argument of `stty` in quotes: `stty intr '^E'`